# Elan Smart Pad - empty settings window

Tags: windows-8, touchpad, asus-laptop

I am using my Asus UL30JT with Windows 8.

I installed Elan Smart-pad driver 11.14.1.3. It basically works just fine, I have all the gestures and stuff. However, to adjust the settings I have to launch regedit.exe, because the window appears to be broken. Under Mouse -> Elan Tab -> Options I see this:

[image: 1]

Do you know how to fix that? Also, if you have a similar program, can you at least send me screens of what I can change? As I said, I am editing registry right now and I need some guidance what I can actually do :)

---

@HaydnWVN I am using registry, because it is the only way to change something.
for example - make the area, where gestures react, a bit smaller. Because othewise, on my rather small touchpad I was always triggering random gestures. I fixed that by changing the field of effect to something a bit smaller.

I found it myself.

@Karan 
Yep, I installed and reinstalled everything, over and over again. Many versions, older, newer, Asus original, only Elans. Sometimes I even forced drivers from completely unrelated, newer laptop models.
The best I got was to launch that settings window, however it was a bit faulty driver and it disabled almost everything. Even Microsoft Driver for PS/2 mouse was better.

Comment: Explain why you are going into the Registry to change settings and why/where you found this information.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the driver and associated software?

Answer (score 4):

Go to the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Elantech\SmartPadDisplay` and change all values to 1. This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: This did not change anything for me, even after a restart and confirming the values had been set to 1.

Comment: Worked for me on ASUS N73S, with Windows 8.1, Elan Touchpad 15.9.5.3_X64_WHQL

Answer (score 0):

Get [the driver from Samsung](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/NP-RV511-A01US). It worked. It uses a different UI.

Comment: This is an old version which does not support Windows 8 gestures (e.g. swipe from right edge to get the charms bar). However, it works perfectly with the hardware and the configuration ui works.