# Lengthy struggle with two finger scrolling on ELAN drivers

Tags: windows-10, drivers, mouse, touchpad, scrolling

After several hours of frustration, I'm giving up.

The default trackpad driver of the Asus UX303U is truly catastrophic. I downloaded ELAN driver 16.21.13.3 which is fantastic, but I am not able to turn on two finger scrolling. (On Windows 10 Home 64 bit.)

There's a lot of online content about this, but nothing works for me.

1. Going to `Settings` and then `Touchpad`, I get the `Your PC has a precision touchpad`. Scrolling down there are many options and among them is `Drag two fingers to scroll` under `Scroll and zoom`. Checking them has no effect.

[image]

Under `Related settings`, going to `Additional settings` and then to the `ELAN` tab, the `options` button is greyed out as depicted below. So I cannot access that either.

[image]

2. When I run `ETDAniConf`, I get the blank window below. Running `ETDSimpleUI` gives an `ETDSimpleUI has stopped working` error.

[image]

How can I enable two finger scrolling? I am desperate.

---

**Added.** Screenshot of `Hardware` tab.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you used `c:\program files\elantech\ETDSimpleUI.exe`? Look in this folder for other programs with similar names and try them.  Try also adjusting sensitivity settings, palm rejection, tapping speed etc. if you can. Asus itself [recommends](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-ZenBook-UX303UB/HelpDesk_Download/) a much older driver for the TouchPad from 2015/11/13, but a relatively new BIOs from 2017/09/11, and both may be worth trying.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your Mouse Properties window's "Hardware" tab?

Comment: @3D1T0R added to the post.

Comment: @harrymc unfortunately I don't even have such an `.exe` file anywhere on my computer.

Comment: Do you have an elantech (or similar) folder anywhere and what .exe files does it contain?

Comment: @harrymc here is a list: `ETDAniConf`, `ETDCtrl`, `ETDCtrlHelper`, `ETDDeviceInformation`, `ETDProperties`, `ETDService`, `ETDUn_inst`, `TocuhpadEnableDisable`.

Comment: Can you please go into the properties of your `ELAN Input Device for WDF`, go to "Details", and list the info you get for both "Hardware Ids", and "Compatible Ids".

Comment: Dear @3D1T0R, thank you for your continued help. `UnderHardwareIDs` I have: `ACPI\VEN_FLT&DEV_0102`, `ACPI\FLT0102`, and `*FLT0102`.  Under `Compatible IDs` I have: `SYN0A00`, `SYN0002`, `PNP0F03`, `PNP0F13`, and `PNP0F12`.

Comment: You state that you're on Windows 10 Home 64-bit, can you also list the Version and Build of Windows 10? This can be found by running `winver.exe`. Here's an example: "Version 1709 (OS Build 16299.371)".

Comment: @3D1T0R Version 1709 (OS Build 16299.431).

Comment: You should really have all [these files](http://www.shouldiremoveit.com/Lenovo-Pointing-Device-22834-program.aspx), so where are they? Your driver installation seems broken to me. Try to uninstall the driver and reboot to let Windows install its own driver. If that doesn't work, try the above Asus driver in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to comment, but my reputation is too low.

Therefore, in an answer: did you try to uninstall the ELAN driver and the default touchpad driver, rebooted your pc and tried to download and install again the ELAN driver? Also, I found this question on the white screen of the ELAN settings: [Elan Smart Pad - empty settings window](https://superuser.com/questions/514119/elan-smart-pad-empty-settings-window); small chance that the first answer would help you:

> Go to the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Elantech\SmartPadDisplay` and change all values to `1`.

Comment: Dear DaanR, thanks for your help. Unfortunately your suggestion did not help me.

Answer (score 0):

The ELAN software is normally installed in the folder
`C:\Program Files\elantech`, but you are missing all the `.exe` files
that should be present there
([list](http://www.shouldiremoveit.com/Lenovo-Pointing-Device-22834-program.aspx)).

So your driver installation seems broken to me.

Try to uninstall the driver and reboot to let Windows install its own driver.

If that doesn't work, try the older driver that is
[recommended by Asus](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-ZenBook-UX303UB/HelpDesk_Download/).

If this still does not work, let us know from where you got your Elan driver,
for verification.

Answer (score 0):

I found another a solution to my own too fast scrolling problem. Go to setting>devices>mouse>. Under "roll the mouse wheel to scroll", check for multiple lines at a time and then slide the slider underneath to choose 2-3 lines at a time, whichever feels more comfy. Next go to your touchpad additional settings and choose multi touch settings>two-finger scrolling>tweak speed as per your liking and choose either auto scroll, interial scroll or continuous scroll or neither.